# JAVASCRIPT Board game: Object spawn on each other

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm writing a board game in JS and I'm stuck right now, I spawn 3 types of object on my grid/board:

- rocks
- players
- weapons

I succeeded on making them spawn randomly but sometimes ( a lot ) they spawn on each others. If someone can help me to solve that problem.

I tried to play with my cells state, by default all cells = 0, for each object spawn cells = numbers.

if cells = numbers find another cells.

Well that how i tried to code it, but all my test have failed.

Here is my code.

```
window.onload = function() {

  init();

  function init() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 800;
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    drawGrid();
    randomRock();
    playerSpawn();
    weaponSpawn();
  }

  function drawGrid() {
    cols = canvas.width / w;
    rows = canvas.height / w;

    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      cells[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        cells[i][j] = 0;

        var x = i * w;
        var y = j * w;

        ctx.rect(x, y, w, w);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }

  function randomRock() {

    var rock = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < 15; r++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(56,56,56)";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#142d0a";
      rock[r] = ctx.fillRect(x * w, y * w, rockW, rockW);
      cells[y][x] = 1;
    }
  }

  function playerSpawn() {

    var imgPlayers = [];

    for (var p = 0; p < 1; p++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);

      imgPlayers[p] = ctx.drawImage(player1, x * w, y * w, playerW, playerW);
      cells[y][x] = 2;

    }

    for (var p = 0; p < 1; p++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);

      imgPlayers[p] = ctx.drawImage(player2, x * w, y * w, playerW, playerW);
      cells[y][x] = 2;

    }

  }

  function weaponSpawn() {

    var imgWeapons = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
      imgWeapons[a] = ctx.drawImage(weapon1, x * w, y * w, weapW, weapW);
      cells[y][x] = 3;

    }

    for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
      imgWeapons[a] = ctx.drawImage(weapon2, x * w, y * w, weapW, weapW);
      cells[y][x] = 3;

    }

    for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
      imgWeapons[a] = ctx.drawImage(weapon3, x * w, y * w, weapW, weapW);
      cells[y][x] = 3;

    }

    for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
      imgWeapons[a] = ctx.drawImage(weapon4, x * w, y * w, weapW, weapW);
      cells[y][x] = 3;

    }
  }
}
```

Here i m back ! I need some help, i want to move my two character with the arrows keys.

My 3 goal : 1- move the player with arrow keys  ---
            2- only to 3 cell on X and Y  ---
            3- one player after another ( turn by turn )  ---

EDIT : i suceeded on the first goal after a lot of try and the collision with my border ( canvas ) Feel good *Y*

Now going for my second and third goal.

Comment: Where in your code is `if cells = numbers find another cells.`?

Comment: I deleted it, wanted to show the clean code.  But  i wrote  it :Ex for weaponspawn .....  if ( cells === 1 || cells === 2) { weaponSpawn(); }   i know that this code wont work, i miss something but cant tell what.

Comment: You have lots and lots of duplicate code. Don't just copy-paste lines all over your code, put them in a function and use that. You also need to watch your row/col and x/y; at the top, it's `cells[col_index][row_index]` but further down it's `cells[row_index][col_index]`.

Comment: thx you for you help. i m learning JS and  try to write a clean code at first and optimize it after little by little. i ll try to fix the duplicate code and the problem abou row/col like you said.  but right now i m focused on my object who spawn on each other.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a function that finds a free cell:

```
function rndFreeCell() {
  var x, y;
  while (true) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
    if (cells[x][y] === 0) break;
  }
  return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

You can use that like this:

```
var cell = rndFreeCell();
ctx.drawImage(weapon4, cell.x * w, cell.y * w, weapW, weapW);
cells[cell.x][cell.y] = 3;
```

To find two cells that are a certain minimum distance apart, use this:

```
function findTwoApart(dist) {
  var cell1, cell2;
  while (true) {
    c1 = rndFreeCell();
    c2 = rndFreeCell();
    var dx = c1.x - c2.x;
    var dy = c1.y - c2.y;
    if (Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) >= dist) break;
  }
  return [c1, c2];
}
```

Now use it like this:

```
var two = findTwoApart(5);
cells[two[0].x][two[0].y] = 1; // playerOne
cells[two[1].x][two[1].y] = 2; // playerTwo
```

Comment: I'm using `true` because I exit the loop using `break` when the randomly selected cell is free, i.e. `0`. `x` and `y` are just used internally, just inside the function; they are then returned by the function as simple object and can be accessed by appending `.x` and `.y`. I could have written `var burgerKing = rndFreeCell();` In that case the found x coordinate is `burgerKing.x`.

Comment: ok i understand your code, forgot the how work the "while loop"  and thx you very much for you help.  May i ask you one more thing,, i dont want the player to spawn close to each other how can i do it ?  just a tips where to look. again thx you

Comment: @Shadowss You could randomly pick two cells until they have a certain minimum distance. I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: @Shadowss You're welcome, and keep at it. I certainly didn't learn all that over night :)